# CSS file not found on GET request

Tags: java, html, css

I have a project with such structure. CSS file is included like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css"/>
```

When I open html file on it's own from my computer, css loads. But when i load it from GET request on localhost, css file is not found.

[image: structure]

Comment: what web framework are you using?

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza i'm not using any frameworks, just a jetty server

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a path mistake.
When you are using two dots before slash sign - browser searches for the file in two folders upper from the current place of **index.html**

The solution depends on where your index file is located, I think that when you put all the thing to localhost your **index.html** is in the root folder, so there is no need in dots before the slash sign, simply make your path like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css"/>
```

Or without "/static/", if you have also moved "css" folder to the root

If you are still calling index from the templates folder - try using this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./static/css/style.css"/>
```

Comment: @EmberTraveller, clarify the error code you get in the console of your browser please, in order for me to be more specific in my answer. Or provide the structure of your "localhost" folders/files

Comment: error is this "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Structure or resource files is in provided image.

Comment: @EmberTraveller, eddited answer for you, if it works (it should now), than you can now understand the dots stuff ;)

Comment: it actually didn't :D . well, maybe it has to do something with jetty, i tried many different variations of paths but nothing worked, just not found

Comment: @EmberTraveller, okay) then go for jetty's documentation about setting a Context Path, maybe you are indeed went wrong in your jetty configs
Here is a link: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-contexts.html#setting-context-path

Comment: Yes! Problem was indeedin my jetty configuration! first time trying it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect. From the image the correct path seems to be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static.css/style.css"/>
```

Comment: folder name is not static.css, it's just idea folds it to it because there is no other folder than css folder

Comment: I see. Check a DOM inspector on your browser to try to verify the error. Seems like a path issue, in any case.